# Is RAM speed relevant for copy tasks in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, memory, performance, clockspeed

I am often working with Excel and notice that when I copy and paste large amounts of data from one spreadsheet to the other (especially after the data is filtered), this operation is executed very slowly. So I wanted to find the bottleneck for this operation and checked the common HW metrics (cpu usage %, network usage, RAM usage % and disk I/O). However those were all far from being 100% busy.
So my question is whether the RAM clock speed could have something to do with this (currently using DDR3 1600).

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give us an idea of how much data you're copying?

Comment: It is not even THAT much you should think, sometimes 100k rows filtered for ~15k entries.

Comment: Is your intent to limit answers to this question to RAM? IMO, the way you asked the question you are only wanting to know if RAM could be the issue. What if it isn't? Then any answer not related to RAM would be wrong, even if it resolved your problem. Make sense? You may want to rewrite your question to be more about the issue you are having, rather than what you think it might be.

Answer (score 0):

It's CPU intensive. The reason your CPU wasn't 100% busy is that the task is inherently serial and can't take advantage of all of your CPU's resources, leaving most of the CPU free to do other tasks.

Comment: well in that case my CPU utilization should be capped at 25% or 12.5% or something like that. However the CPU usage is 4% according to task manager. And when looking at the logical CPUs they are ALL used and not just one up to a 100%. This cannot be an explanation, i have verified that with some testing.

Comment: @Hellbender123 They're all used because a single task is migrating from core to core, still running on only one at a time.